# Separate exposed sort form from exposed filter block

Tags: views

Is is possible in Drupal 8 Splitting exposed filters and exposed sort & pagination i.e. placing sort & pagination inside a separate block and filters in another block?

Right now there is no out of the box solution to this. In my opinion this would greatly improve user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see solution for such issues.
But I solved these issue with custom form elements and using the hook_views_query_alter.
In the hook_views_query_alter you can alter orderBy property.